# Is there a way to find out the number of tag-page views?

Tags: support, tags, views

When curating tags, I sometimes think to myself questions like:

> Are people clicking on this tag to look at the corresponding collection of questions?

Hence...

**Question**: Is there a way to find out the number of tag-page views?

I feel like this would be a useful data point when deciding whether or not to burninate a tag: if people are clicking on the tag to browse those questions, it's a sign it's worth keeping.  If nobody ever looks, I feel there's probably not a big distinction between it existing or not existing.

I understand I can go into a page [such as this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/topusers), and it gives some question/answer statistics.  But I get the feeling sometimes people tag questions with certain tags only because (a) they have to choose some tags, (b) they happen to think of some random word at the time of writing, not because the tag is actually useful.  And having these non-useful, yet extant tags inhibits proper tagging.

Comment: They're probably measured in Google Analytics, but there's no way for users / moderators to find out.

Comment: In SOes, a CM once provided details about page views of wiki pages: [¿Qué páginas wiki de etiquetas reciben más visitas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4132/83)